# Avoiding database locks on SQL Server 2012 when updating using Java

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a web application which is based on SQL Server 2012, and I use Java to update data in the database. (Windows Server 2008, JSP, Tomcat7, Java7)

The relevant code is as follows:

```
public static synchronized int execute(String dsName, String packageAndFunction, List fields) {

        // prepare insertStr
        String executeStr = buildStatement(dsName, packageAndFunction, null, fields);
        dbConn  = DBConnection.getInstance();
        Connection conn = dbConn.getConnection();
        CallableStatement stmt = null;
        int result = RESULT_FAILED;
        try {
            stmt = conn.prepareCall(executeStr);

            // fill statement parameters (each ?)
            fillStatement(stmt, fields);

            stmt.execute();
            result = stmt.getInt(fields.size());

        } catch(SQLException e) {
            Log.getInstance().write("Exception on executeGeneral (" + packageAndFunction + ") " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                stmt.close();
                dbConn.returnConnection(conn);
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                Log.getInstance().write("Exception on executeGeneral (" + packageAndFunction + ") " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        return result;      
    }
```

About 90% of the time, the code works great. The rest of the time there is some kind of lock on the table which will disappear by itself in perhaps half an hour or so. The lock prevents even simple SELECT queries on the table from executing (in SQL Server Management Studio). In severe cases it has prevented the entire application from working.

I had an idea to use `stmt.executeUpdate()` instead of `stmt.execute()`, but I have tried to research this and I do not see any evidence that using `stmt.execute()` for updating causes locks.

Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose with that code.  The next time that it happens, pull up your activity monitor on the SQL server and see what sql command is holding the lock.

Comment: OK. Will do, and then I will update the question

Comment: Hi Darthg8r... Thank you - I was assuming that there was a problem with the Java, when in fact there was a lock on the table caused by trying to UPDATE and SELECT at the same time.

Comment: and Darhg8r - if you repost as an answer, then I will accept it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to diagnose with that code. The next time that it happens, pull up your activity monitor on the SQL server and see what sql command is holding the lock.

Comment: Thanks... I in fact had trouble finding the sql command holding the lock with the activity monitor (CTRL-ALT-A) but did have success with the script from http://sqlserverplanet.com/troubleshooting/blocking-processes-lead-blocker which told me it was SPID=58. I then did `DECLARE @SPID INT; SET @SPID = 58; DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@SPID)` to find the SQL script. I could have then killed it with `KILL 58`